# Faild creating ovirt_image during Install OKD 4.12 on ovirt 4.5

Tags: okd, ovirt

I try to install OKD 4.12 on ovirt 4.5.
But It was failed to creating ovirt image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bCUp.png)

i was waited for 30 minute.
But there is no change.
I checked The Storage Disk Page at oVirt Engine Manager.
But It was stopped to download ovirt image.
Progress bar was stopped.

Please how to solve.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFQ3X.png)

I tryed to install oVirt Version from 4.10 to 4.12.
It was still.